# solving the Lions, Wolves, and Goats

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to tackle the Lions Wolves and Goats problem found [here](http://unriskinsight.blogspot.com/2014/04/goats-wolves-and-lions.html)

```
-- Lions Wolves Goats
-- Lion -> Wolf -> Goat :: -1, -1, +1
-- Lion -> Goat -> Wolf :: -1, +1, -1
-- Wolf -> Goat -> Lion :: +1, -1, -1
--                      -------------
--                      :: -1, -1, -1
```

This is what my solution looks like:

```
eat :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
eat (lions, wolves, goats) = eat (lions - 1, wolves - 1, goats - 1)
eat (0, wolves, goats) = eat (1, wolves - 1, goats - 1)
eat (lions, 0, goats) = eat (lions - 1, 1, goats - 1)
eat (lions, wolves, 0) = eat (lions - 1, wolves - 1, 1)
eat (0, 0, goats) = (0, 0, goats)
```

This code compiles but the code hangs forever. I'm pretty sure I've missed a match but I don't know what. Please let me know how to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: With GHC 7.10.3, the compiler gives a very helpful warning that happens to be the cause of your problem. It's trying to help you, don't ignore it!

Comment: You have overlapping patterns, as a warning should tell you if you enable them. Indeed, the first equation covers _any_ input triple, so the last ones are never used, causing an infinite loop. Also, the problem seems to be much more complex than implied by the code above: it involves a non-deterministic transition system and we need to compute all its final states. We need to do a graph visit, essentially.

Comment: Note that this seems wrong `eat (lions, wolves, goats) = eat (lions - 1, wolves - 1, goats - 1)`  who eats them all?  You should have three different alternative outcomes from this state.  You also don't have other terminal states for leaving only lions and only wolfs.

Answer (score 3):

Patterns are read top-down, left-right. Therefore, your first pattern matches all others. Reorder them:

```
eat :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
eat (0     , 0      , goats) =     (0         , 0          , goats    )
eat (0     , wolves , goats) = eat (1         , wolves - 1 , goats - 1)
eat (lions , 0      , goats) = eat (lions - 1 , 1          , goats - 1)
eat (lions , wolves , 0)     = eat (lions - 1 , wolves - 1 , 1        )
eat (lions , wolves , goats) = eat (lions - 1 , wolves - 1 , goats - 1)
```

Note that this assumes that all values were originally positive. If one of them was negative, you will still get loop. Also note that you're missing to other "stable" states and your logic for a non-zero pack of lions, wolves and goats is off. If there are goats *and* wolves, a lion might eat either of them. Furthermore, a wolf might eat a goat before a lion does.

That's the part where non-determinism will come into play.

Comment: For non-determinism, look up the list monad.

Comment: @PyRulez: If you use the list monad only, it's going to be horribly slow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, works but not tidied up since implemented the first thing that came up to my mind.  I'm sure it can be improved...

let's define the state we're going to keep track of as (lions,wolfs,goats)

```
type State = (Int,Int,Int)
```

the eating rules are given as

```
lw,lg,wg :: State -> State
lw (n,w,g) = (n-1,w-1,g+1)
lg (n,w,g) = (n-1,w+1,g-1)
wg (n,w,g) = (n+1,w-1,g-1)
```

since at each step the number of steps will exponentially grow, it's better to remove redundant states and non permissible ones (negative values), define helper functions

```
nonnegative:: State -> Bool
nonnegative (n,w,g) = n>=0 && w>=0 && g>=0
```

core of the program is the step function where we apply the rules to current states

```
step :: S.Set State -> S.Set State
step s = S.unions [mapfilter lg s, mapfilter lw s, mapfilter wg s]
```

here the uniqueness is outsourced to Data.Set using qualified with S prefix, requires the import

```
import qualified Data.Set as S (Set,toList,unions,singleton,map,filter,null)
```

mapfilter is applying the eating rules and filtering nonnegatives.

```
mapfilter f s = S.filter nonnegative $ S.map f s
```

we'll compute the steps until we have a solution

```
solution :: S.Set State -> State
solution s | S.null final = solution $ step s
           | otherwise = result s
           where final = S.filter done s
```

where two elements of the state is zero

```
done (n,w,g) | n==0 = w==0 || g==0
             | w==0 = g==0
             | otherwise = False
```

and retrieve the first result from the Set

```
result :: S.Set State -> State
result s = head $ Prelude.filter done $ S.toList s
```

using the initial values referenced in the link

```
initial :: S.Set State
initial = S.singleton (6,55,17)
```

we get the result when we run with the initial state

```
Prelude> solution initial
(23,0,0)
```

that is 23 lions.

**UPDATE**

I cleaned up the code little bit, still returns the first solution found

```
import Data.Set (Set,toList,singleton,map,filter,null,union,empty)

type State = (Int, Int, Int)   -- lions, wolfs, goats

lw,lg,wg :: State -> State
lw (n,w,g) = (n-1,w-1,g+1)
lg (n,w,g) = (n-1,w+1,g-1)
wg (n,w,g) = (n+1,w-1,g-1)

done,nonnegative :: State -> Bool
done (n,w,g) | n==0 = w==0 || g==0
             | w==0 = g==0
             | otherwise = False
nonnegative (n,w,g) = n>=0 && w>=0 && g>=0

step :: Set State -> Set State
step s = mapfilters [lg,lw,wg] s

mapfilters :: [State -> State] -> Set State -> Set State
mapfilters [] s = empty
mapfilters (f:fs) s = union (mf f s) (mapfilters fs s)
      where mf f s = Data.Set.filter nonnegative $ Data.Set.map f s

solution :: Set State -> Set State
solution s | Data.Set.null final = solution (step s)
           | otherwise = final
           where final = Data.Set.filter done s

run = head $ toList $ solution $ singleton (6,55,17)
```

Comment: Remark: there isn't necessarily a single solution. If you start with (1,1,1) you can end up with (2,0,0) (wolf eats goat), (0,2,0) (lion eats goat)  or (0,0,2) (lion eats wolf). You probably want to add that to `solution` or `result` as a comment.

Comment: The program already computes all solutions, it is just throwing away all but the first. Strange choice. solution should probably have type `Set State -> Set State`. And in `result`, you do `filter done`, but you already did `filter done` in `solution`. So just return that: `| otherwise = final`.

Comment: in one iteration there may be more than one solution and can be returned all, but there may be other solutions in future iterations, however using the first solution found as the termination condition.

Answer (score 0):

One key to doing this efficiently is to realize that the problem only *looks* asymmetrical. In each step, there are three possibilities:

1. There is only one type of animal remaining. This is the final state.
2. There are two types of animal remaining. In this case, a specimen of the missing animal is created, and the two pre-existing types reduce in number by one each.
3. All three types of animals remain. In this case, one of them increases in number while the other two decrease in number.

Because of this symmetry, we only need to think about the *numbers*, and not think too much about the *animals*.

Since the total number of animals goes down by one in each step, the way to get the most animals remaining in the end is to keep the number of steps as small as possible. So what does it take to get the number of animals down to exactly one? Well, that means getting the other two types of animal down to exactly zero. This sounds trivial, but it's actually a key insight!

Suppose we already know which animal we want to survive. How do we get as many as possible? I think you can convince yourself that there are only two ways to improve the situation: either increase the number of winners, or make the numbers of losers more balanced. Making the number of losers *less* balanced (the only other option) will decrease the number of winners (bad in the short term) and lengthen the game (bad in the long run). At each step where there's a choice, either of these choices is equally good. So it remains only to figure out who should win.

The problem specifies 17 goats, 55 wolves and 6 lions. The significant thing about this is that 17 and 55 are both odd, while 6 is even. At each step, *all three parities change*. Therefore, the only two that can hit zero at the same time are goats and wolves. Though there are only 6 lions to begin with, they must ultimately survive! Whenever the numbers don't all have the same parity, the winner must be the one that's different from the others.

When all three numbers have the same parity, the easiest way to pick the winner is to calculate the score for each possibility and select the largest. How do we calculate the score? Suppose we select goats to win, and the numbers are labeled `g`, `l`, and `w`. So we need `|l - w| / 2` balancing moves to balance the lions with the wolves. We additionally need `(l + w)/2` moves to kill off the lions and wolves. So the total number of goats in the end is `g - |l - w|/2 + (l + w)/2`. Thus

1. If there are more lions than wolves, there will be `g + w` goats in the end.
2. If there are more wolves than lions, there will be `g + l` goats in the end.

You can now calculate the final configuration in *constant time*, and you can calculate a path to reach it in *linear time*.